# event.target.value not working after enabling lockerservice

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

event.target.value not working after enabling lockerservice in lightning.
Can you guys help me with this? Thanks

Comment: I did a quick test from Lightning developer guide pg-117 which makes use of event.target.value which works pretty fine with locker service enabled.
Probably you need to handle both the framework event and the native browser event.

Answer (score 11):

You guys must know that if you are using *lightning* component for eg.

```
<lightning:button label="Submit" value="xyz" onclick="{! c.handleClick }" />
```

You can't access it's value attribute using

```
event.target.value
```

because DOM is not accessible due to locker service.
You have to use

```
event.getSource().get("v.value")
```

And if you are using simple html attribute then you can get it's value normally using DOM event eg.

```
<div value="Test" onclick="{!c.myFunc}">CLick Me</div>
<a href="#" onclick="{!c.myFunc}" value="123">click me</a>
```

You need to write in that case

```
event.target.value
```

Answer (score 8):

Remember that locker service uses a component capability model, and unless you "own" the component where the event was triggered, you will not be able to access its internal, including its value attribute.

**"owning" means: the component is in the same namespace, or the component is created in your *.cmp markup or programmatically from your own component.**

Under normal conditions, for DOM events, if you can set the listener, you can also access `currentTarget` instead of `target`.

**`event.target` points to the emitter, and `event.currentTarget` points to the recipient of the listener.**

This is a very tricky issue, because unless you own something, you can't inspect it. We will get someone to investigate more, but we will need more information from you:

- how are you defining the listener?
- what component is the event emitter in your code?
- it seems that you're dealing with input elements, what component are you using to create that input element?

Comment: How does this apply to LWC?

Answer (score 4):

We are also facing this issue in our code. Anyhow we are going with an alternate and recommended way to do this, which is replacing the `event.target.value` with the following line:

```
event.getSource().getElement().value
```

You might find the [source code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/event/Event.js) useful.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use it .However got the error "TypeError: event.getSource is not a function"

Comment: @Gautam Could you post a small code snippet to explain your scenario. Our scenario might be different from yours

Answer (score 4):

You need to handle both the framework and native browser event

```
    if (event.getSource) {
        // handling a framework component event
          target = event.getSource(); // this is a Component object

    } else {
       // handling a native browser event
       target = event.target.value; // this is a DOM element
   }
```

If in a component event if `event.target.value` is used then it will be undefined